# How to use a string variable in psycopg2 select query?

Tags: python, psycopg2

Error while fetching data from PostgreSQL column "u62194" does not
exist

```
sql = """select userid from myusers WHERE userid='u62194' """ Of
course the hardcoded value works as it should.

import psycopg2

def select_tables():
    someuserid = 'u62194'
    print(someuserid)
    """ Run a select using a variable that is a string """
    sql = """select userid from myusers WHERE userid=%s """ %someuserid
    conn = None
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect(user = "postgres",
              password = "xxxxxx",
              host = "127.0.0.1",
              port = "5432",
              database = "mydb")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute(sql, (select_tables,))
        print(cur.fetchone())
        cur.close()

    """ "myusers" table: id     userid 1      u51884 2      u62194 3      u26922  """
```

I should get: u62194

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're using the query parameters incorrectly. Pass a list instance as a parameter to the `execute` function to pass your query parameters. From memory the psycopg2 manual explicitly discourages doing this in the manner you were trying.
Try something closer to this:

```
import psycopg2

someuserid = "u62194"

conn = psycopg2.connect(
    user = "postgres",
    password = "xxxxxx",
    host = "127.0.0.1",
    port = "5432",
    database = "mydb"
)

cur = conn.cursor()

# Use a list here to insert query parameters into the query string.
cur.execute(
    """
    SELECT userid 
    FROM myusers u
    WHERE u.userid = %s;
    """,
    [someuserid,]
)

result = cur.fetchone()

print(result)

cur.close()
```

Comment: I tried that but still get same error: "column 'u62194' does not exist"

Comment: I've cleaned the answer up somewhat and tested it. Can you try the version I've provided? I can get it to work correctly here on my system with test data ( Using Python3 FYI ).

Comment: The above works gloriously!  Why I did not check in with 'stack' earlier I cannot answer. I have worn myself ragged with my old code.  Using the SELECT and the variable INSIDE the cursor let it work.  Hats off to ajxs for this beautiful solution.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you! Could you 'accept' the answer as the solution using the tick symbol?